# Marklogic Javascript for loop

Tags: marklogic

I have multiple json format.  How can I loop throught json files to display developers' name.  Thanks

example:

```
doc1.json

{
 "script": "collectionlib.sjs"
 "version": "1.0.1"
 "Developers":"Melvin Mckee"
}

doc2.json

{
 "script": "TechReports.sjs"
 "version": "1.1.5"
 "Developers":"Brenton York"
}
```

I can do for single json file.

```
 'use strict';
  var doc = cts.doc("/doc1.json")
  var node = xdmp.toJSON(doc)
  node.root.Developers

//Return result: "Melvin Mckee"
```

but not sure how to construct For..Loop to get result back developers name are "Melvin Mckee" and "Brenton York"

```
var items = cts.uris(null,
                    null,
                    cts.collectionQuery("scripts-collection")
           ) 

for (var i = 0; i < items.length;i++){
     var doc = cts.doc(items[i]);
     var node = xdmp.toJSON(doc); 
     node.root.developers
  }
```

I got result NULL on Qconsole.

Comment: Not sure what are you assigning to items variable, but as long as items is an array of filepaths, your code is perfect, i.e. if for example your items variable is ['/doc1.json', '/doc2.json'], it will work.

Comment: I got NuLL from Marklogic Qconsole.  It should return "Melvin Mckee" and "Brenton York".

Comment: Hmm, I am not familiar with marklogic, try asking another question about why marklogic is returning null, but your for loop is perfectly fine and should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem is the `node.root.developers` has a lower-case 'd', while the data you provided has an upper-case 'D'. That may have been a typo.

MarkLogic returns the value of the last expression, but the for loop doesn't return a value. What you want to do is declare an array variable before the loop, add to it during the loop, then return that variable.

Try this:

```
let uris = 
  cts.uris(
    null,
    null,
    cts.collectionQuery("scripts-collection")
  ) 

let devs = [];

for (let uri of uris) {
  let doc = cts.doc(uri);
  let node = xdmp.toJSON(doc);
  devs.push(node.root.Developers);
}

devs
```